# Layering divs using position and z-index is not working

Tags: html, css, razor, telerik

Using **cshtml** and trying to make a text appear in front of an image and it isn't working.
I am using a third party commercial tool to generate what I need from the cshtml, so I supposed it just doesn't support layering, but I need to rule out first that I am not doing anything obviously wrong.

Sample code:

```
<div id="cover-img-content">
    <img src="images/Cover.png" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: contain"/>
    <div class="cover-page-text">
        <h1>TITLE</h1> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#cover-img-content { 
position: relative; 
width: 550px;
height: 770px;
z-index: -1;
}

.cover-page-text {
top: 20%; 
left: 10%; 
position: absolute;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 5px dotted black; 
z-index: 1;
}
```

The best I get is the title below the image, and the image with much different dimensions to the pixels I've specified in the style (some 2 x 2 cm square..). The borders also don't show up, so it's hard to tell where the parent div is.

Could anyone experienced with html + css suggest any common mistake I made be making before I declare it being an issue with the third party tool?

Comment: I can't work out what the point of those z-index settings is. Could you explain? Thanks.

Comment: Those tiny snippets of code do not appear to actually reproduce the problem, https://jsfiddle.net/0k6xjong/

Comment: @AHaworth from what I've read z-index is meant to show the order in which the elements shows up, i.e. which is in front and which is behind.

Comment: They are not relevant in this case as children can't go beneath the parent element anyway, and the img is 'painted' before the absolute element which has the text in it. I doubt if it's a relevant point here, but may be worth removing the z-index properties just in case it's muddling something. Can you show us the actual HTML/CSS that is produced (use your browser devtools inspect facility to find this) as@CBroe says, there isn't enough to go on in your question so far.

Comment: @CBroe the code snippet is showing basically what I want to happen, but in reality, it is not what is observed. I guess this shows my code is fine and it's the third party tool that is causing the problem

Comment: @AHaworth oh I see, thanks for the tip. I had also tried without the z-index too, but the effect is the same. I can't show the actual html/css because it's used for document generation, the output is a Word document in the end, not a web page.